# Google Chrome does not resize content when toggling overflow property

Tags: css, google-chrome, hover, overflow

I have a `div#pane` element with `overflow:hidden` in regular state, `overflow: auto` in the 'hover' state. Inside that div there is a `div.content` element.

When `div#pane` gets hovered, `div.content` is resized to accommodate the vertical scrollbar. However, when the mouse pointer leaves `div#pane`, `div.content` does not change its width, even though the scrollbar is no longer visible.

This behavior manifests itself only in Chrome, Firefox handles this OK.

[jsFiddle to play with](http://jsfiddle.net/P2DaD/3/)

Comment: I dont see much of a difference. in my ff is doesnt do anything either

Comment: @DiederikEEn, what version of Chrome are you using?

Comment: 26.0.1410.64 @tokarev

Comment: I use the same version. You are supposed to see a red band when the scrollbar disappears @DiederikEEn

Comment: is the background color `c00` needed?

Comment: @DiederikEEn, no. This is just to illustrate that .content gets resized

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed to fix the problem with Javascript, though it feels like some black magic. If there is a CSS solution, I'd be happy to accept it.

```
/* force redraw of the node */
$(".content").on("mouseleave", function () {
   var el = $("<div></div>");
   el.appendTo(this);
    setTimeout(function () {
        el.remove();
    },1);
});
```

[jsFiddle with this solution](http://jsfiddle.net/P2DaD/5/)